# How to rotate image - canvas pixel manipulation?

Tags: javascript, canvas, image-rotation

I use getImageData and putImageData to draw on canvas from a buffer canvas. I use these methods because I have a large number of particles and these proved to provide the best performance.
Now I'd like to add rotation of particles but I'm having problems with that.
Here is a jsfiddle which uses transformation matrix for rotation. As you can see in the picture (or fiddle) there are holes in the resulting image which I kinda expected from using this matrix.

```
nx = ~~ (xx * Math.cos(angle) + yy * Math.sin(angle) + cx);
ny = ~~ (xx * Math.sin(angle) - yy * Math.cos(angle) + cy);
```

But I don't know how to make this better, especially when I'm looking performance effecient solution?

---

### [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dfar5oej/1/)

Image - square after rotation (square is used as a simple body):

[image: square after rotation]

---

*Currently my backup is procedurally generated sprite animation which is prepared in advance with standard canvas states: save -> translate -> rotate -> restore.*

Thank you very much for any directions you can give me.

Comment: I'm quickly checking older projects but right now I'm not sure how i dealt with it. I know that I did decide on some compromise and pump the performance up in some other area. I think one of the things I used was to just prerender every new procedurally created image into its own canvas and use standard canvas rotate function to get all the frames needed for the animation of that particular object. Basicallly, I prepared sprites on the fly as much in advance as was possible while making sure I destroy others that couldn't be repurposed.

Comment: It's alright, I was getting the white/blank pixels in the middle and didn't knew what to do, I wasn't able to solve and removed rotation from my canvas game.

Comment: Well, I'd advice you to simply use canvas rotate. It's pretty efficient and if you use hardware acceleration you won't feel it at all unless you get into humongous numbers of sprites. Though, I'd first check if you could get better results with one large canvas and save - trans - rot - rest routine or with several smaller ones just for each of your sprites - or at least a few separate canvases for differently sized images - and rotating them there with the same routine and then just drawing from these canvases into your main one (I think canvases per image gave much faster result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to map a single pixel to a single pixel.  When you rotate an image, each pixel in the original can influence any of the surrounding pixels in the new image.  You are effectively mapping the top left corner of each pixel to it's location in the new image, but you need map the center of each pixel to it's location in the new image and then check the overlap of this rotated pixel with that location, and the 8 surrounding pixels in the new image.

[image]

Here you can see the effect.  The yellow dots are the centers of the pixel which find the "home" location for the pixel (i.e. where the majority of the influence will be placed).  You then need to figure out the percentage of that pixel (the underlying blue/white grid) cell is covered by the original pixel (black box surrounding the yellow dot).  Once you figure out the home location influence, you need to repeat that process for the 8 surrounding pixel with respect to current pixel in the original image.  In your current code, you are using the top left corner of each pixel to find the home pixel for the new image.  You should use the center of the pixel.

Since multiple iterations might affect the same pixel, you'll need to calculate the transformation in a buffer before drawing it to the final image.  For pixels in the transformation that are not fully covered by pixels in the original image, figure out the percentage of the pixel that is covered and use that to influence the alpha channel.  You'll have to take care when applying the pixels to the final image that you account for the alpha portion and blend with what's already there.

Comment: ...your picture is worth a thousand words, nice clear answer!

Comment: Thank you, I thought about it in this way too, Although, I should have stressed more that performance is the key thing here. I'm using 2d canvas so the amount of steps/calculations in this case cuts animation of 10000 particles significantly down. But I'm still trying to figure out a way which goes I guess half way one road and half the other one ;-). Any way thank you very much for ensuring me that this point of view is the way to go that really boosts the morale :-).

Comment: If performance is your primary concern, I'd expect that the built in functionality (_save -> translate -> rotate -> restore_) is actually the fastest you'll get because the implementation of the built in functions is not limited to javascript and could possible take advantage of hardware functionality.  There are of course some simple hacks you could do to improve perf regardless, e.g. only allow N possible rotation angles and then just paste the same rotated image to all of it's various places.  If you have 10,000 different images, you'll have to try other things.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually doing something similar you just noted, but when I use canvas methods as you mentioned I can barely draw a few thousands particles with movement. But I'm putting together all the things you mentioned and combining it with something else hopefully if will work out but I have never done this before so I'm hitting a wall more than I'd like to :-). Thank you I'm so grateful for your advice.